# Parse countObjectsInBackground on big classes

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, parse-platform

Parse says that on classes with over 1000 objects, the countObjectsInBackground method will become slow and inaccurate. When I use this method however, I set the limit to 1 because I only want to know if one instance of an object exists. That is to say, regardless of the size of the class, I wish to count at most one object from said class. Is this fine, or will I experience problems with this as my class size grows? If so, what are some alternatives? I feel using getFirstObjectInBackground would be slow because it must download the object, and I have no use for the object in this case anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be fine.  But just to be safe, consider instead using `find` with a limit = 1, or `getFirst`, both provided by PFQuery.  The existence test using find is whether the resulting array has > 0 elements.  For getFirst, check whether the resulting object == nil.

**EDIT** you can make an explicit existence test by implementing something like the following in cloud code...

```
Parse.Cloud.define("objectExistsInMyClass", function(request, response) {
    var query = new Parse.Query("MyClass");
    query.first().then(function(result) {
        response.success(typeof result != "undefined");
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: would find be slower that count? And I can't find the first function, could you elaborate on that one please?

Comment: Based on somewhat opaque statements from parse about this, I think find and first will be faster.  These are clearly where parse (and mongo, I think) have done the most optimization.  And since we're limiting to one, there's trivial cost in transmitting the one object.  My bad on "first", the family of functions are called "getFirst" in iOS... see here: https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:

Comment: I see, between getFirst and find do you thing getFirst will be faster, even if the limit is set to 1 on find?

Comment: They are probably indistinguishable, but I'd go with getFirst.  Maybe getFirst just calls find for you, with limit=1 (indistinguishable), or maybe, its narrower functional goal provides an opportunity to optimize.

Comment: You might get additional savings by making a cloud function that does the first or find and then returns the count.  Especially if the objects in the class are large, you can avoid the transmission.  (In could code, the js sdk calls first "first()").

Comment: So by performing the function via cloud code, it could save me time because no object will have to be locally downloaded, it will be downloaded on the cloud, with the count returned to me?

Comment: yes, but not a count, just an existence test.  i'll paste in an example in an edit.